# Burndown chart for a specific Teams "Area" in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, devops, agile, backlog, burndowncharts

In Azure Devops, we have a few Teams set up - one of the bigger teams has multiple areas under it.

We'd like the option to have a backlog assigned to the "Team" - so all our team members can see the backlog as a whole and also the backlog per area (which works).

But when we filter a sprint to current iteration and the area we want to analyze, the Burndown Trend graph created is for the Team and not filtered to that area path.

For clarity. Say we have the Team "The Big Company"

Then under that we have areas for each of the small companies the "Big Company" owns, so;

**Big Company**
|

- Small Company 1
  |
- Small Company 2
  |
  etc

We want to see the backlog for the "Small" companies by viewing the unfiltered "Big Company" backlog and we may want a Burndown for "Big Company" too.

But also, we want a burndown for each "Small Company" area.

Hope that makes sense! Is it possible please?

Thanks :)

Have tried filtering the Sprint to the Team/Area combo we want to view and this sprint view displays the data we want, but then clicking on the Burndown graph in the top right ignores the "Area" and shows the burndown for the "Big Company" only...

We had each "Small Company" set up as its own Team, which obviously allows a Burndown for each, but then cannot see a combined Backlog/Sprint view for each of the Small Companies.